# Java EE versus .NET development estimates

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee, comparison

**This is not a request for opinions.**  Please only respond if you are

1. a strong Java EE/Oracle developer
2. a strong .NET/ server developer, and
3. have developed nontrivial web apps in each framework.

My question is what is the relative development time for a given specification in each platform.
Let's say for the sake of comparison that there is a 5 man, 3 month project in .NET, would it take more, less, or the same amount of time to develop in Java EE given Java EE developers of comparable skill?

This is not a hypothetical question since we have to reestimate a .NET project in Java EE.

Comment: Given the level of information provided, that question is impossible to answer in any meaningful way. Either framework is great, and most projects would probably take about the same time, given the developers know the frameworks. Look at your project, and what is required if there is nothing in the requirements that suggest Java over .Net then choose whichever your developers are more proficient at.

Comment: Indeed. Since this is not hypothetical, talk to *your* developers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given developers of equal talent in each respective platform, I'd say that development would take about the same amount of time. There are some things that each platform does better, but without further information, I'd say it's about the same.

Comment: Although I'd be inclined to argue the J2EE solution would be 5x (over) engineered just by nature ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the amount of time needed to complete a project does neither depend on the technology used nor can it simply be calculated by the teams size. 
The main factor for a projects time are the developers: their skills, their motivation and their individuality. Some people are very effective in plain C. Others never get things done in Java EE, although it only requires a fraction of code lines.

Answers to this question sonly can be subjective.